# Google Spreadsheet API Developer

Tags: google-sheets

I am no longer trying "to embed Google Maps so when I click on it opens Google Maps with 100 meters radius." I understand "Google Maps is not a part of the core services.

I am now trying to use a Work Around without Google Maps and am now asking for help with the "Work Around"....
I want to be able to use the method from this YouTube video to create the Search option another Google support team rep(Vienna) referred me to. In the video he did a search for shoes, shirts and dresses to find his customers. I want to do a search by zip and/or city and state to find mine...."Google Sheets - Search, QUERY function"===https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSGKO5gx974

I need help with this part as well with the Google Sheets function list. Which Google Sheet function or a combination of functions will allow me to do the 150-200 meters radius search within the "Google Sheets"? I am not tech savvy and need help to determine which ones can be used. Here are some of the functions that appear to be able to be used from what I think  FLATTEN, FREQUENCY, LINEST, MAP, MMULT MDETERM , SUMX2PY2, DAVERAGE, DCOUNTA, DSTDEV, DVAR, DELTA, FILTER, SORT, SORTN, UNIQUE, QUERY, ISFORMULA, CELL, ect.... ===https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en#query=

The Viennes also sent a link.  [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/support#:~:text=Before%20you%20call%2C%20make%20sure,1%2D877%2D355%2D5787](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/support#:%7E:text=Before%20you%20call%2C%20make%20sure,1%2D877%2D355%2D5787)
As I was looking over the page, I came across the link to theMarketplace.
I was wondering which one of those databases could be used in the function to accomadate what I am trying to accomplish. Is it the Zip Code Tabulation Area, Geolocation API, CARTO, Roads, API, Routes API. Maps JavaScriprt API, ect....

With those three things listed above, I am sure something can come close to doing a radius/range search in Google Sheets.

If any, at least by the City and/or State search.

I am in need of a Developer, can you suggest one?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Is there a way I can attach the google spreadsheet here?

Comment: Brokerage Agent Email Phone Cell Number Lane  Shipper Shipper Contact  Notes                  
ABBA Freight Systems LJ Falk lj@abbafreight.net 541-690-3477 541-761-1755 Fresno, CA 93706 Scelzi Enterpries 559-237-5541 HS                 
Able Transport Solutions Dakota Giese dgiese@abletransportsolutions.com 402-268-4963 402-438-4940 Eagle Pass, TX 78852 Progress Rail Bensa/Bravo Yesika Ramirez/ 830-773-4141

Comment: Second sheet, I want to be able to search for these brokers by the city&state and/or zip code...